# Commerce Server 2007 sp2 and ASP.NET Integrated Pipeline

Tags: .net, integrated-pipeline-mode, commerceserver2007

I am using Microsoft Commerce Server 2007 sp2 and a custom ASP.NET 2.0 website. Everything works well in Classic Pipeline, but when I try to use the Integrated pipeline, it fails with the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Request is not available in this context
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
   System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request() +11189992
   System.Web.TraceContext.InitRequest() +269
   System.Web.TraceContext.VerifyStart() +133
   System.Web.TraceContext.Write(String category, String message, Exception errorInfo, Boolean isWarning, Boolean writeToDiagnostics) +162
   System.Web.TraceContext.Write(String category, String message) +69
   Microsoft.CommerceServer.Runtime.CommerceDataWarehouseAuthenticationModule.Init(HttpApplication appInstance) +67
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +124
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +1162
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +312
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +133
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +341


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5416; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5419
```

This is a website that was upgraded from Commerce Server 2007 to Commerce Server 2007 sp2.

I have followed the instructions at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/commserver2007/thread/8eabc7fb-ccfa-48e3-9c29-d43bf03cc438 to add the web.config section, but it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: post your web.config minus any personal/confidential stuff and I may be able to help.

Comment: our commerce server msft rep told us to leave it as classic mode enable 32 bit true, he couldn't get integrated to work

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx

you might also want to check out the starter site sp2 code... the web.config in there may help you.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=10f9c18e-3e15-4ab9-9c40-a424876d1630&displaylang=en